# Modifying sort columns in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to programatically modify the sort definition that is sent to the server when a user clicks on a column to sort it. I have added a `onSortCol` function to my grid configuration. In that function, I need to check whether the "Id" column is in any sort position other than the last position. If it is, it should be removed.

Here is what I have tried:

```
onSortCol: function (index, iCol, sortOrder) {
    var grid = $(this);
    var rawSorts = index.split(",");
    if (rawSorts.length > 1) {
        var idFieldIndex = -1;
        var processedSorts = [];
        for (i = 0; i < rawSorts.length; i++) {
            var currentSort = rawSorts[i].match(/[^ ]+/g);
            if (idFieldIndex === -1 && currentSort[0].toUpperCase() === "ID") {
                idFieldIndex = i;
            }
            processedSorts.push({
                field: currentSort[0],
                direction: currentSort[1] || sortOrder
            })
        }
        if (idFieldIndex !== -1) {
            processedSorts.splice(idFieldIndex, 1);
            for (i = 0; i < processedSorts.length; i++) {
                if (i + 1 < processedSorts.length) {
                    grid.sortGrid(processedSorts[i].field + " " + processedSorts[i].direction);
                }
                else {
                    grid.setGridParam("sortorder", processedSorts[i].direction);
                    grid.sortGrid(processedSorts[i].field + " ", true);
                }
            }
            return "stop";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please could you explain more detailed what you need to implement? Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` or not? You wrote "how to programatically modify the sort definition that is sent to the server". If you use pure server side sorting and you need just change the information which will be sent to the server then you need just to use `serializeGridData` or `beforeRequest` to modify the data which will be sent to the server.

Comment: Basically what i need to do is remove sorting by the "Id" column unless it's the last sort column. I have `datatype: json` and `loadonce: false`. The reason I was trying to implement this in `onSortCol` using the built in sorting method as opposed to simply modifying the post data as you suggested is that I assumed that approach would also require me to remove the sort icon manually.

Comment: So you have "Id" column in the grid. Is it correct? And you want to deny sorting by the column? Why you not just include `sortable: false` in the definition of `Id` column in `colModel`.

Comment: I don't want to disable sorting by the "Id" column entirely. I just want to deny sorting by that column ahead of any other columns. The "Id" column is the initial sort column of the grid, so when a user attempts to sort by another column without first removing the "Id" sort, it has no effect since "Id" is unique. I'm just trying to give a little help to users in this scenario.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow you. **Do you use `multiSort: true` option** which you not mention till now? In the case the clicking on any other column follow to sending to setting `sortname` with comma separated string with the columns and the value will be sent as `sidx` parameter. I suggested you before to use `serializeGridData` or `beforeRequest` to change the information which will be sent to the server. For example **you can modify `sidx` inside of `serializeGridData`** (remove `Id` for example). Is it what you need?

Comment: Yes, I failed to mention, I have `mulisort: true`. If I remove the sort column directly from the post data, how do I ensure that the sort icon does not appear on the column header?

Comment: there are no `mulisort: true`, but `multiSort: true`. Removing of the icon is easy, but you still don't described exactly what you need. There are many implementation possibilities to what you ask, but to recommend you once till I know what you do. The most simple implementation seems to me the following: you don't use any `sortname` in the grid initially and you sort by `Id` on the server side if `sidx` is empty. It seems you need nothing more to do.

Comment: Your suggestion to remove the default client side sort and move it to server does seem like the simplest solution here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple implementation seems to me the following: you don't use any `sortname` in the grid **initially** and you sort by *Id* on the server side if `sidx` is empty. It seems the only what you need to do to implement your requirements.